# Complex hash function collision probability

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$C_a(u) = au\, \text{mod} p \, mod \, \Delta , \; C_a(v) =  au\, \text{mod} p \, mod \, \Delta$ where $a \in \{0,1,2 \ldots p-1 \}, p$ is a prime number and $\Delta $ is any number less than $p$. If $C_a(u) = C_a(v)$, then it is given that $a(u-v) \, mod \, p \in \{-1 \Delta, -2 \Delta, \ldots \ -\lceil\frac{p-1}{\Delta} \rceil \Delta,0, 1 \Delta, 2 \Delta, \ldots \ \lceil\frac{p-1}{\Delta} \rceil \Delta \}$. How is this derived? Kindly help. I am clueless. Source - research paper related to hashing.

It is asking me to delete the question. But it is not allowing me when i try to delete it. I had genuine doubt. The answer enlightened me. Thank you for the answer. I am trying to delete it as it was voted to delete it. It helped me. May be the guidelines need to be revised? or allow me to delete it rather than vote against it and sink in the curiosity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C_a(u)=C_a(v)$ then $a(u-v)\,{\rm mod}\, p \ \rm mod\, \Delta=0$. So the quantity $a(u-v)\,{\rm mod}\, p $ must be an integer multiple of $\Delta$. But this quantity  also must be strictly between $-p$ and $p$, because of the ${\rm mod}\, p$ operation. Thus $a(u-v)\,\rm mod\,p$ is any integer multiple of $\Delta$ between $-p$ and $p$. Therefore it must lie in the set you have written. To see this, notice that $$\left(\lceil\frac{p-1}\Delta\rceil + 1\right)\Delta\ge\left(\frac{p-1}\Delta+1\right)\Delta=p-1+\Delta\ge p,$$ hence $\lceil\frac{p-1}
{\Delta}\rceil\Delta$ is  the largest multiple of $\Delta$ that is less than $p$.

Comment: I know that 2p values go to 0, 1, 2 .... $\Delta-1$ buckets. Because of symmetry, around (on an average) 2p/$\Delta$ values go to 0th bucket(oth bucket means numbers(between -p and p) divisible by $\Delta$ ). But how is that largest number less than or equal to p-1 which is divisible by $\Delta$ is (p-1)/Delta * Delta. How is $\frac{p-1}{\Delta}$ is an interger? kindly elaborate

Comment: understood now. thank you. we are taking ceil of p-1 divided `by delta

Comment: The fraction $\frac{p-1}\Delta$ is not necessarily an integer, but it is at least $1$ since $\Delta < p$. If you apply the ceiling operator the result will be an integer, hence $\lceil \frac{p-1}\Delta\rceil\Delta $ is an integer multiple of $\Delta$.